# Unable to Debug Typescript on VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to debug a typscript project from vscode on Windows 10 using WSL as the default shell but getting the following error when I click the run button

```
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -e npm run build" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

What am I doing wrong?

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\app.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "ts-sample",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "dist/src/app.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node dist/src/app.js",
      "prestart": "npm run build",
      "build": "tsc",
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"    
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": ""
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
      "url": ""
    },
    "homepage": "",
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0",
      "eslint": "^7.11.0",
      "remove": "^0.1.5",
      "tslint": "^6.1.3",
      "typescript": "^4.0.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "inversify": "^5.0.1",
      "json-merge-patch": "^1.0.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13"    
    }
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {      
    "esModuleInterop": true,            
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "lib": ["es2017"],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./**/config*.json"
  ],
  "exclude": [ 
    "./dist/**/*",     
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

All the npm related commands in the package.json such as `npm build`, `npm start` etc. work fine from the shell